# Terminating App with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on making my Application compatible with iOS 10 beta. But unfortunately the App is crashing as soon as it starts. I have check all the IBoutlets and connection in Main.storyboard which are perfectly fine. Also it working fine in iOS 9.3.2 i.e in Xcode 7.3.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I had the same problem ... for me it was because I copy/pasted a storyboard `UIViewController` from an old objective-c project into my new swift project.  Once I dragged a new `UIViewController` object onto the storyboard and reset the class, my outlets were working, and no crash.

Comment: Try to change your deployment target to `iOS 10` minimum and then recompile and run.

Comment: What is the reason of the exception?

Comment: @YoCoh I have not copy/past anything from old project. I have just running the existing code in Xcode 8 and it is crashing as soon it launches the splash screen.

Comment: @doNotCheckMyBlog I have tried with this but no success.

Comment: @vadian App is showing these logs while crashing . As such no reason.
2016-07-04 15:42:34.778906"AppName"[3452:159347] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: are you using any c++ file code and your file extension is not in .mm

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem with Xcode 8 beta. And if turn off wifi and run the app, it doesn't crash anymore without network. So the problem might be in NSURLConnection or related to any web service sync/async call.

Comment: @Natarajan there is a issue with Wi-Fi. I have turn off Wi-Fi and its working fine. I am still working on the solution. I will post something as soon as i will find the solution. Thanks

Comment: I also have same issue, we suddenly noticed it on new iOS 10. At least is seems to appear only on this device, but failing to narrow down issue.

Comment: What kind of app are you making? In some instance this is related to Info.plist which info is not set as required in the app run. And will just crash without any error log prior to that error.